# Using Recycler view inside Sticky Scroll view not working

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a requirement where I need to code a screen which has a info view in top and  view pager with two tabs in the bottom. View pager has two tabs with Recycler View inside it.

The View pager should stick whenever the user scrolls up and then the recycler view inside it should start scrolling. To achieve this I created two separate fragments for top part and bottom part and wrote the xml like this.

```
<com.citi.mobile.dashboard.views.StickyScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/core_color_FFFFFF_white">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/title_id"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="sticky">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Inside the the bottom container I have a View Pager.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/TransTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/core_color_0077bb_blue"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/core_color_0077bb_blue"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/ledgerTabLayoutTextAppearance"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/core_color_666666_grey"
    custom:typefaceName="Roboto-Medium" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/transaction_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

This has two tabs and each has a recycler view inside this. When I run this the parent scrollview stops working and only the recyclerview scrolling works.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to the recyclerview in your xml.

Comment: tried already... it just makes the recycler view fixed thats it. Whole screen stops scrolling